# How to upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04?

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, do-release-upgrade

Is this the best way to get 18.04.6 upgraded to 20.04?

https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/04/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-20-04

I get these messages when I attempt to upgrade:

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade -c

Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS develoment release set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.
```

Why is it telling me there is no development version available? I want a production LTS version, no interest in a development version. I am able to ping [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) so not sure what it's saying about internet proxy settings.

Comment: same output wo the "-c" option.

Comment: Move to the next line of your output: Test https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts in a browser. Does it work?

Comment: I don't know if there is such a thing as "the best way". You might want to rephrase it.

Comment: I'd always recommend reading the release notes for the release you're going to (ie. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes) where you'll see an "*Upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS or 19.10*" section.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -h
```

For more details browse [How to upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS today](https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-18-04-lts-to-20-04-lts-today).